# Run code after text-to-speech stops talking on Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I need to run some code but **only** after the text-to-speech stops talking. 
I am currently delaying a few seconds but that is not really dynamic, is there any solution for this problem? Can I get notified when the voice stops talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to implement the TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener interface and set your code to run during the onUtteranceCompleted() implementation.

There is an example of this in the Android Developer resources:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

Comment: You are right! :) with this addition we are good to go! HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
String destFileName = "/sdcard/myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";
myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, wakeUpText);
mTts.synthesizeToFile(wakuUpText, myHashRender, destFileName);